# How to recover precious photos in iCloud from stolen iphone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

My iPhone was lost or stolen and I have lost all  my children's photos and need  to know how to get into my iCloud account by using a kindle, tablet or a windows phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows Phone 8 you can set up iTunes on your phone and try to access your photos on iCloud.

It might not work but it is worth trying.

[Follow instructions here how to:](http://gigaom.com/2013/12/22/windows-phone-8-and-the-mac-surprisingly-compatible/)

Then try this to get the Photos [moved over to the sky-drive](http://nokiaviews.com/windows-phone-and-icloud-email-contacts-calendar-and-photostream.html).

iCloud Photostream sync with Windows Phone.

There are some [good instructions here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/07/18/how-to-icloud-photo-stream-windows-8-pc/), but I can not verify for you since I do not have Windows 8 Phone.